# Jekyll: Liquid Capture and Markdownify Tag Issues

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

In Jekyll, I am trying to include a paragraph of "site information" that should go on a certain amount of pages in my website.  The file structure of the certain information I am dealing with is a "team"folder->"_posts"folder-> then within the "_posts" folder is "site_information.md" and many other markdown files of pages that I want to include the "site_information.md" in.  I do not want to use an includes statement on every single file in "_posts" folder if possible, so I want to make an includes statement in the "layout.html" file.

#### Here is what I have tried in the "layout.html" file:

```
{% if page.page == "page" %}
  {% include_relative site_information.md %}
  {{content}}
{% endif %}}
```

The code above included the information I wanted, but it did not include it in markdown format.

#### I then tried this:

```
{% if page.page == "page" %}
  {% capture site_info %}{% include_relative site_information.md %}{% endcapture %}
  {{site_info}}
  {{content}}
{% endif %}
```

This code does not display the "site_information.md" information on the pages at all when using the capture tag.

#### I then tried this:

```
{% if page.page == "page" %}
  {% capture site_info %}{% include_relative site_information.md %}{% endcapture %}
  {{site_info | markdownify}}
  {{content}}
{% endif %}
```

This code gave me the error when using the markdownify tag:
Liquid Exception: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass in     _layouts/layout.html

Does anyone know how to fix this so I can use an includes statement in the layout to properly display a markdownified file on a number of web pages?

Comment: Do I understand that you want to be able to add this *site information* conditionally on any page or post in your site with the test `{% if page.page == "page" %}`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: But a relative include cannot be relative to `index.html` and to `post/123456-mypost.md`. Why not an `include` with the same test ?

Comment: Using a regular include tag, the site information was displayed on the page I wanted, but it was not in markdown format.  Then I used a capture tag with the same includes statement with a markdown tag as well, and that is when I start to get the error: Liquid Exception: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass in _layouts/layout.html

Comment: did you have github repository?

Comment: I would like to upload to a repository on github but this stuff is kind of private.

Comment: @HealyFuess did you try including YAML frontmatter to `site_information.md`? That is, three dashes (-), then enter, then three more dashes. see if that makes a difference, and try method one again.

Comment: Yes, that weirdly did not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are not trying to apply the `markdownify` filter to empty text. You will get `Liquid Exception: undefined method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass` if there is no text to markdownify.

Since you say that

> This code does not display the "site_information.md" information on the pages at all when using the capture tag.

using the `capture` method while it does not import any text will likely cause an error.